# Keep getting 'Type cannot be implicitly converted from void to string'

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to write a program for college. The intended purpose is it is supposed to take students surname and test score and write them to a text file. I keep getting this error. I don't know what to do. The code isn't finished yet I still need to write the other functions for it hence the empty spaces.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Assignment2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "StudentTestScores.txt";
            StreamWriter SW = File.CreateText(path);

            string sUsrOpt = "";
            byte bNumStudents = 0;

            Console.Write("Enter Amount Of Students In The Class (Max 20): ");
            byte.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out bNumStudents);

            string[] sSurnames = new string[bNumStudents];
            float[] fScores = new float[bNumStudents];



            mainMenu(sUsrOpt, sSurnames, fScores, ref bNumStudents, SW);

            Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Open File...");
            string temp = "";
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sr = File.AppendText(path))
                    for (int i = 0; i < bNumStudents; i++)
                {
                    foreach (var line in (path))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("");

                        temp = sr.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write("Surname: {0}", temp);
                        Console.WriteLine("");

                        temp = sr.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write("Score");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("press any key to continue");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                }

            }




            Console.ReadKey();

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);

            SW.Close();
        }


        //The menu

        private static void mainMenu(string sUsrOpt, string[] sSurnames, float[] fScores, ref byte bNumStudents, StreamWriter SW)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nOption A - Open and display a test\nOption B - Enter and save a test\nOption C - Help\nOption D - Exit");

            Console.Write("Choose An Option: ");
            sUsrOpt = Console.ReadLine();


            switch (sUsrOpt.ToUpper())
            {
                case "A":
                    Opentests(sSurnames, SW);
                    break;
                case "B":
                    EnterAndSaveaTest(fScores, sSurnames, ref bNumStudents);
                    break;
                case "C":
                    Help(fScores, sSurnames, SW);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    Exit();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
        //Enter and save a test
        private static void EnterAndSaveaTest(float[] fScores, string[] sSurnames, ref byte bNumStudents)
        {
            if (bNumStudents > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too High, try again");

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < bNumStudents; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Surname {0}: ", i + 1);
                sSurnames[i] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Enter Score For {0}: ", sSurnames[i]);
                float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out fScores[i]);
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < bNumStudents; y++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fScores[y]);
            }

        }

        //Open a test
        private static void Opentests(string[] sSurnames, StreamWriter SW)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please input a previously entered surname");


        }


        //Gives help to the user
        private static void Help(float[] fScores, string[] sSurnames, StreamWriter SW)
        {


        }
        //Ends the program
        private static void Exit()
        {
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not provide your entire code-base but just that portion of your code which is relevant in order to reproduce your issue. In particular please provide where you get that error.

Comment: Which line gives this error?

Answer (score 2):

path is a string, you need to open the file (I would use a StreamReader)
then read each line from the StreamReader

```
foreach (var line in (path))
```

Then it looks like you are trying to read from a writer

```
temp = sr.WriteLine();
```

WriteLine is a void return, you can't assign something with no return to a value.